# How do I change the NLS_CHARACTERSET setting on Windows 7 for Oracle 11g ODBC client

Tags: windows, oracle, nls-lang

I'm trying to retrieve data from an Oracle database into MS Access or Excel on to a Windows 7 PC.  The data includes characters such as degree and diameter symbols.  These are not displayed correctly on the PC.  I can see that the data is stored correctly using the dump function in my query, and that it is the translation to the client character set that not bringing them in.

By looking at this query, and also querying the database parameters with `SELECT * FROM NLS_database_PARAMETERS`, I can see that the `NLS_CHARACTERSET = US7ASCII`.  I think this is cause of the problem as the diameter symbol etc is not included in this character set.

But, I've checked the registry to see what NLS_LANG is set to, and it is `ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8MSWIN1252`.  I know that I'm looking in the correct registry key because when I change the language/territory (to `GERMAN_GERMANY` for example) it does change for my queries.

I've also checked for an environment variable that is overriding this setting and couldn't find one.  I trying creating an NLS_LANG environment variable with the same settings as above but that didn't make any difference.

My Windows code page is set to 1252.  The database `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` setting is `AL16UTF16`.

Any ideas of what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

If `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is set to `US7ASCII` then you will never get any special characters from it. With `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=AL16UTF16` you should get any character, provided the data type of your column is `NVARCHAR2` or `NCHAR` (not `VARCHAR2`)

Set your local `NLS_LANG` to `ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.AL32UTF8` then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response Wernfried.  My question is how do I set NLS_LANG to the correct characterset on the client?  Nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: In your registry or as environment variable as you did already

Comment: Thanks Wernfried.  I think I'll try it on a different PC.  Editing the registry or creating an environment variable hasn't worked on this one...

Comment: Note, there are two locations: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\NLS_LANG` for 64 Bit and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\NLS_LANG` for 32 Bit. Set the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information @Wernfried.  I only have an HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\ key in my registry.  That makes sense I guess as I only have a 32 bit version of the ODBC driver.  If I make an edit to the language and/or territory in this registry setting then the change is picked up in the query the next time I close and reopen Access.  But the language stays as US7ASCII whatever I put in the registry entry.  I don't understand why!

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say the characterset stays as US7ASCII (not the language).

Comment: The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is a database value, this you cannot change (at least not in an easy way).  `NLS_LANG` on your client is needed to properly translate your local characters (eg. Windows CP1252) to database characters (e.g. AL32UTF8). Only stuff like weekday names or error messages are defined by language and territory values.

Comment: Ok, I understand a bit more now.  I mistakenly thought the NLS_CHARACTERSET was the local client character set as defined by the last part of the NLS_LANG parameter.  It looks like I can't display what client character set is actually being used as, according to the nls_lang_faq on the Oracle website, the <clients characterset> part of NLS_LANG is NOT shown in any system table or view.  So, if I assume that it is changing when I alter the value of NLS_LANG in my registry, why is the query not displaying the correct characters?